# android - how to use TextToSpeech with api 21

Tags: android, text-to-speech

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
    private TextToSpeech tts;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tts = new TextToSpeech(this,this);

        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        PhoneStateListener callStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

                if(state== TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING ){
                    tts.speak(incomingNumber+" calling", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Phone is Ringing : "+incomingNumber,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {

    }
}
```

But the function `speak(String text, int queueMode, HashMap params)` is deprecated in API Level 21. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you are rigth, it is deprecated, until **API 21** you used to use:

```
public int speak (String text, int queueMode, HashMap<String, String> params)
```

but this method was deprecated in **API 21**.
As of API level 21, replaced by:

`public int speak (CharSequence text, int queueMode, Bundle params, String utteranceId)`

in your case:

```
...    
tts.speak(incomingNumber+" calling", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
```

just pass a `null` to the `utteranceId` parameter

more Info about the [Text To Speech](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#speak(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: Why someone should take the effort to post to stackoverflow to pass null?  That third parameter has a significance..  right?